# Updating/multiple .csv files into single dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, updating

Hello I am attempting to create a single dataframe with multiple .csv files from a folder that will be updating/added to.

I have found previous answers on here however I am having a rather simple error

> Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
>     'file' must be a character string or connection

```
dir<-"asdfasdfasdfasf/asdfasdfs" #change this to your directory

temp <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
importDM<-lapply(temp, read.csv)

rawDM<-read.csv(importDM, header = TRUE)      #will read csv
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong!

Cheers,

Comment: `do.call(rbind, lapply(temp, read.csv, header = TRUE))` should work.  `importDM` is a list, not a character string; that's why the last line is giving you an error.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see in the call to the list.files function you should add the path parameter and assign "dir" to it. 
The variable importDM is a list and the rawDM variable is not necessary since you called read.csv in lapply already.
If the files have the same sructure of data you can convert importDM to a data frame with as.data.frame. If the list elements don't follow the same structure that it is a bit more work.

This is a working example whit three csv files.

```
    dir <-"./data" #change this to your directory
    temp <- list.files(pattern="*.csv", path = dir, full.names = TRUE)
    importDM<-lapply(temp, read.csv, header = FALSE)
    df <- as.data.frame(importDM)
```

Each csv file contains three numbers (1,2,3 - 4,5,6 - 7,8,9)

Comment: Thank you Valter, this has done it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
temp <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")

dataset <- do.call(rbind,lapply(temp,
read.csv,header=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it -

```
dir<-"asdfasdfasdfasf/asdfasdfs" #change this to your directory
temp <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
importDM<-lapply(temp, read.csv)
rawDM <- do.call(rbind, lapply(raw, read.csv, header = TRUE))
```